# Merging objects back after applying boolean difference modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I've difference booleaned part A from part B, which is fine but, I was wondering if theres anyway to merge the two now separate objects back to make them as one rather than editing them separately?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Press the apply button on the boolean modifier. Select one object, press shift while selecting the other object (so that both of them are selected but the last one remains as the active object). Press Ctrl+J to join.